# Flex column wrap block don't stretch

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem with flex column wrap. I need to dynamically add content.

It may be 1 or 6 items which should be in the center of the block. So I need a flexible `<ul>`.

But when I use column wrap and `<ul>`, I don't want to stretch and `<li>` is overflow. Each `<li>` should be aligned left. I didn't find any solutions to fix it so far.

```css
.block {
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 1px solid red
}
li {
  tex-decoration:none;
  list-style:none
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
   <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As @dippas said, it is a bit unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve.

What I did notice is that you may be applying the **block** class to the wrong element.

Remove the `class="block"` from the <div> and add it to the <ul> instead, so it becomes:

`<div><ul class='block'`...and so on.

Comment: I correct my questions. hope now it looks cleaner

Comment: Finally, it should look like this - http://prntscr.com/jhggnk

Answer (score 0):

The edit I suggested earlier in the comment, when applied should look like this:

```css
.block {
  display:flex;
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid red
}

li {
  tex-decoration:none;
  list-style:none
}
```

```html
<div>
   <ul class='block'>
    <li>Tag_name_1</li>
    <li>Tag_name_2</li>
    <li>Tag_name_3</li>
    <li>Tag_name_4</li>
    <li>Tag_name_5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The snippet below looks fairly close to what you have in the print-screen. The flex will only affect immediate children, in this case, the `<li>` items. Which is why you need to apply the class **.block** to the `<ul>` element.

More information on how flexbox works here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* `flex-direction` to be column? If not, just set the `<li>`'s to have a `flex-basis` of 50%.

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.color-block {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="color-block" style="background-color:blue;"></span>Tag_name 1</li>
    <li><span class="color-block" style="background-color:red;"></span>Tag_name 2</li>
    <li><span class="color-block" style="background-color:green;"></span>Tag_name 3</li>
    <li><span class="color-block" style="background-color:yellow;"></span>Tag_name 4</li>
    <li><span class="color-block" style="background-color:purple;"></span>Tag_name 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```